# Wrong transparent backgrund with PHP-GD

Tags: php, centos, php-gd

I've got a problem with php-gd, I use php-gd to resize png with transparent background file. after that, I put the resized png with `<img>` and set a background color `#wheat` on HTML file.

But the background color is not pure wheat, there is 'brushed metal' on background.
[image]

I've tried to use another Server B to resize png file with same code, it works prefectly with transparent background:
[image]

So I think this it's a environment issue, because I run same code on these servers.

Here is the environment info with 'brushed metal' background image:

```
OS: centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64
PHP: 7.3.16
PHP-GD: 2.3.0
```

[image]

The environment info with work perfectly:

```
OS: centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64
PHP: 7.1.19
PHP-GD: 2.1.0
```

[image]
Do you guys have any idea with that?

Thank you so much!